# passport-github, req.query.redirect is not correct

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I want redirect to my custom url.
But `req.query.redirect` is undefined.

Here is my route:

```
app.get('/auth/github', (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    const redirect: string = encodeURIComponent(req.query.redirect);
    let successRedirect: string;
    if (redirect) {
      successRedirect = `/auth/github/callback?redirect=${redirect}`;
    } else {
      successRedirect = '/auth/github/callback';
    }
    passport.authenticate('github', { successRedirect })(req, res, next);
  });

  app.get('/auth/github/callback', passport.authenticate('github', {
    failureRedirect: '/login'
  }), (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    res.redirect(301, req.query.redirect || '/');
  });
```

`successRedirect` is `/auth/github/callback?redirect=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com`

But when navigate to `/auth/github/callback`,

`req.query` is `{code: "bb7d0e867b3aa40f507f"}`,

where is my `req.query.redirect`?

I expect `req.query.redirect` is `https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com`.

Answer (score 1):

From what I know, the callback URL that Passport will use the one that is configured for the strategy when it was instantiated:

```
passport.use(new GitHubStrategy({ callbackURL : ... }))
```

AFAIK, you can't dynamically set that URL.

However, you can store the URL to redirect to in the session instead:

```
app.get("/auth/github", (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  req.session.redirect = req.query.redirect;
  passport.authenticate("github")(req, res, next);
});

app.get("/auth/github/callback", passport.authenticate("github", {
    failureRedirect: "/login"
  }),
  (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    res.redirect(301, req.session.redirect || "/");
  }
);
```

(untested)

Comment: yeah, I put redirect to `req.session`, but it seems there is something wrong with  `res.redirect`, it give me an error:  `Cannot GET /auth/github/https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com`

Comment: It looks like the redirect was URL-encoded, which it shouldn't be. The goal is not to pass it as a query/URL parameter, but as a full proper URL.

Comment: But I still weird why `req.query.redirect` is undefined? I read `passport` source code, did not find the key.

Comment: `successRedirect` isn't the same as `callbackURL`. Only the latter is used in the authentication process itself. If you want to get it working like that, you need to set the `successRedirect` for the _second_ `passport.authenticate()` call (the one passed to `/auth/github/callback`).